# Lighting Study for Dynamic Sign Measured In Footcandles

Tags: qgis

I was assigned to create the attached lighting study to show how bright, and at what distance, an LED-style public sign would illuminate the surrounding area.  The numbers and data came from a chart I was given by the producer of the LED screen.  I had to hand draw it in Google Earth, using angle measurements and distances with lines and circles.  Then I had to manually label each intersection for angle in degrees, and distances with the Measure tool.  The the yellow line is 0° (Y) from the axis of the LED screen (X).  Also had to label the level of luminescence in "footcandles" which are labeled in white on the attached image.

Is there a way I can set up a model in QGIS to automate most of this?

Not only would it save time for when I have to do this again, the results would also be more accurate.  Though I have a lot of experience with ArcMap desktop, modeling was not part of my former position. I have some limited experience with it however.  I also don't have access to ArcMap desktop in my new position.  I currently am using QGIS and Google Earth for mapping tasks.

[image: Lighting Study Example]

Comment: Do you want QGIS to add all the red and yellow arcs and lines and also calculate the white labels?  How is the bearing of the yellow line determined?

Comment: That would be ideal, as it would save time labeling everything in Google Earth once I export the shapefile to a KML.  The bearing of the yellow line was given to me by the sign producer. It was described as 277° from North (as 0°), though their example had me label the direct view of the sign face as 0°.  I measured out to the other angles from there.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but the method I tried it requires two basic layer to work:

- A point layer representing your light/signage:
  [image]
- A table containing the brightness values (imported from .csv):
  [image]

From there I built the model with a few different inputs (note that the number of rings could be added as an input and used as a variable in the tools):

- The point layer
- The total distance, outer ring (integer number input)
- The spoke angles, angular size of a pie slice (int)
- The final spoke angle, since your example had a diffent angular size (int)

[image]

The model then goes through these basic steps to build the geometry:

- project points according to the angles provided (9 different directions)
- create spokes from the projected points
- create a multi-ring buffer, transform it to lines, then split it with the spokes and removing unneeded features and duplicates
- create points on intersections

Along the way, certain attributes are added to the spokes and rings that help in the next steps:

- Add angle and distance from the light to the points layer
- Filter duplicate points
- Drop unneeded fields from the points layer
- Calculate a field containing the matching brightnes values from the table layer according to the angle and distance

Here's the model, visually:

[image]

Here's the result with inputs of 20° spoke angle, 75° final spoke angle, and 150m distance. It's not perfect, there's a single unneeded line segment outside of the visual cone that's due to a weird split in the original line layer that is culled, but it's easy to fix manually:

[image]

[image]

The to symbolization shown above could be saved as a .qml and linked to the model as the default for the output points layer. It's not pretty, it could be refined, but it works.

If specifics of the expressions used in the model are needed, I'll amend the answer with details. Important to note that the values will be matched to the points only if the angle and distance values from the table and the model input match.

Comment: This is great, I will try the same model on my end and share the result when complete.

Comment: @Gordon I fixed some things in the model and now everything can be done in one go, including adding the brightness values to the points, so yes, what you asked is entirely possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'll want to start a model and look at the algorithms for "Create Wedge Buffer"; that will get you started. You could also accomplish this using points only and some trigonometry, but won't appear as the example you provided.

Labeling for sector angles, ranges, and light values may best be accomplished with 3 different sets of points from the vertices of the wedges.

If the angular, radial, and light value figures don't need to change, you can set it up so the user need only click on a point as input and provide a bearing.

Let me know if you need further guidance.

Comment: After I posted this question I found the "Create Wedge Buffer" in a tutorial, which is a good first step.  But, yes I believe for signs this size, the light values remain the same along with the radii.  The angles however would change depending on where the sign would be placed near a roadway.  I believe the light measurements would vary for signs that are both larger and smaller, but cannot confirm that at this time.  What steps would be needed to set the parameters for a model with the option to change the angle of the sign face, and possibly the intensity of the light they emit?

Comment: Let's get some more clarity on this problem:
1) There are 2 angles we are discussing here, the bearing/orientation of the sign face (what direction is it pointing, ie, west or 270°), and the angles that form part of the polar coordinate pair (angle and radius) for each of the measured values. I get that the sign orientation would need to change for each installation. Are you saying the angles for the polar coordinate pairs (0, ±20, ±40, ±60, ±75) would also need to be variable?

Comment: To clarify, no the angles for the polar coordinate pairs would not need to be variable.  Only the angle of the 0° yellow line emanating from the lighted sign would vary from installation to installation.  I did not make that clear in my last response.